# Best way to copy files in ftp using edtFtpNet

Tags: .net, ftp

I am **using edtFtpNet** for uploading binaries of my application to the ftpSite, **I need an option of copying these files from a directory in the server to specific client directories on the same server.**
Scenario:
While updating the app, i upload the binaries to a centralized location on the server, then after verification that all files are properly uploaded, i copy these to the respective client folders. What is the best way to go about it?

I could upload these again from my local but that would be too much heavy and would take too much time. 
Please note that i need copy functionality, not cut..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can move a file from one directory on the server to another directory on the server using the rename operation. This operation is usually used to rename a file, but an also be used to move a file.

So if, for example, you have a file called myfile in a directory called dirA and you want to move it to another directory dirB then you can rename the file from dirA/myfile to dirB/myfile.